# NavLink не видит свойство activeClassName

Tags: reactjs

NavLink не видит свойство activeClassName

```
const Item = (props) => {
    return (
        <NavLink exact className={style.item} to={props.link} activeClassName={style.active}>{props.children}</NavLink>
    )
}
```

Вот что получается в итоге

```
<a activeclassname="Item_active__x8BCv" aria-current="page" class="Item_item__WOzIc active" href="/report">Отчеты и формы</a>
```

Класс active добавляется, но должен был переименоваться для модуля css, а вместо этого выводит такую ошибку.

> Warning: React does not recognize the `activeClassName` prop on a DOM
> element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
> attribute, spell it as lowercase `activeclassname` instead. If you
> accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
> element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В React Router 6 больше нет свойства `activeClassName`. Вместо этого в `className` передается функция, в которой можно определить, является ссылка активной или нет, и вернуть соответствующий класс:

```
<NavLink className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? "red" : "blue"} />
```

Пример из документации - https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#active-links

Answer (score 0):

Либо так `className={({ isActive }) => isActive ? s.active : undefined}`